# Creating logs from controllers in CakePhp

Tags: model-view-controller, cakephp, history, logging, controllers

What is the best way to create logs & history in CakePHP. I was thinking if there is a way to create a Helper "that accesses" one table and then I call this helper inside of each controller that I want. However, I have read that this is not MVC standard. How would it be the correct way to do that?

I appreciate your time spent answering me that. Thanks!

Comment: what kind of logging are you talking about?

Comment: I was talking about logs and history of user's behavior such as editing a form, or creating a registry or deleting a registry and so forth. It has to be in database (model- logs)

Answer (score 0):

Just implement a different log engine for that purpose. The CakeLog class actually works somewhat like an observer and the log engines like listeners.

Simply use CakeLog::write() and your custom engine that could load your log model in the constructor using ClassRegistry::init() and pass the incoming data from write() to the model.

The manual will help you with that. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#creating-and-configuring-log-streams

Comment: Thank you very much. Will that code work with model. For instance, saving into a table every data I want, such as, user editing a form, user creating a registry, user deleting a registry, and so forth?

Comment: Sure it will if you make the log engine work that way. What *exactly* do you want to do? Your question does not really explain that in detail.

Comment: I am so sorry about my terrible explanation and thanks a lot. I am going to check that out and see if I can figure out my log system.

Comment: Simply use CakeLog::write() and your custom engine : this cannot be your answer, its useless

Comment: Instead of crying you should follow the link in my answer which shows in detail how to do it... But ok the link was outdated, so how about telling me this instead of crying? However I've updated it. Your comment is as well useless because it lacks of an explanation *why* my answer is useless.

Answer (score 0):

thats what behaviors are for.

I use the LoggableBehavior from here:
https://github.com/alkemann/CakePHP-Assets/blob/master/models/behaviors/logable.php

works like a charm. they are then fetched and displayed in the view, if you want to.